# how to copy an executable file with python?

Tags: python, executable

How can i copy a .exe file through python? I tried to read the file and then write the contents to another but everytime i try to open the file it say ioerror is directory. Any input is appreciated.

EDIT:
ok i've read through the comments and i'll edit my code and see what happens. If i still get an error i'll post my code.

Comment: Please specify on which platform you are facing the issue, the failing code snipper, the complee traceback and the complete stat info of the file

Comment: @Abhijit, is there any OS other than Windows which uses .exe files? Or were you looking for a specific version?

Comment: @Mark, specific version. I am more concerened about the version as "ioerror is directory" is particularly disturbing.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, EXE files are used by DOS,OS2,Windows,OpenVMS, and a few more. I think DOS is the only one I've listed without python.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to copy a file [shutil copy/copy2](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) should be the tool you should use. Now regarding your particular case, please privide the code and the complete TraceBack to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this with open/read/write, you should to set the 'b' character on both files.

```
outfile = open('output.exe', 'wb')
inpfile = open('input.exe',  'rb')
```

Also, explicitly setting the mode is required when opening for write

Comment: But it should be noted that this is not the best way to simply "copy a file".

Comment: I agree, but thought there was some value in trying to get the original attempt going.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista and 7 will restrict your access to files installed into the Programs directories. Unless you run with UAC privileges you will never be able to open them.

I hope I'm interpreting your error properly. In the future it is best to copy and paste the actual error message into your question.

Comment: @Abhijit, I'm assuming the error message was garbled a bit from the original, thus my suggestion to use copy and paste. I hate playing guessing games as much as anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use shutil.copyfile(src, dst) or shutil.copy(src, dst). It may not work in case of files in the C:\Program Files\ as they are protected by administrator rights by default.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just open it in binary mode, example:

```
with open('file1', 'br') as f:
    src=f.read()
with open('file2', 'bx') as f:
    f.write(src)
```